# Firebase rules and validations for update existing data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a data structure as following:

```
    {
     "users" : {
      "31J59dq1clZ3inHMzoopiigsEg63" : [ {
       "name" : "Lanchana",
       "timestamp" : 1516916245423,
       "uid" : "31J59dq1clZ3inHMzoopiigsEg63",
       "userEmail" : "*****@gmail.com",
       "total-stars" : 123
        } ]
      }
    }
```

and fire rules as following:

```
    {
      "rules": {
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null",
            ".write": "!data.exists() || data.child('uid').val() == 
                       auth.uid && auth != null",
                }
         }
       }
    }
```

I can add new data successfully but I cannot make any updates to the existing one. for ex: If I want to update only total-stars of a particular user based on the uid, how can I specify write and validation rules?

Answer (score 3):

Your data structure seems to have a layer `0` that is missing from the rules. If that layer indeed exists in your actual JSON, you'll want to have it in your rules too:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "$postid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null",
          ".write": "!data.exists() || data.child('uid').val() == 
                   auth.uid && auth != null",
        }
     }
   }
}
```

I called the layer `$postid` here. You may want to use a name that better reflects what the layer represents.

Comment: I added the $postId, but It's working for neither read nor write the new or existing data.

Comment: In that case update your question with the minimal (standalone) code that is causing problems. It would also be preferred to see you actual JSON, instead of a hand-typed approximation. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I updated the actual JSON object. Sorry, My bad It doesn't have the zero index.

Comment: Thanks for that. We're still missing the code that is failing though. And the code that is failing, preferably with the error message you get (if any).

Comment: I've updated the written write rule to ".write": "!data.exists() || $uid === auth.uid && auth !== null" and it started working for both nonexisting and updating an existing data. Thanks for all the help.